# java.io.IOException: Broken pipe spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

our application is running with spring boot 2.3 and deployed on CaaS (kubernetes).

when calling rest end point it is internally calls another rest service and before getting the response
from the second service the first service is throwing following error in the logs and in the postman
it is giving

`504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.`

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:an]
```

on Local server it is working fine.

we increased connection time out and request timeout in application.properties But it did not work.

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=300000
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=300000ms
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: You could change your API so that it has two endpoints, one which returns a request ID and starts the call to the other service, which is performed asynchronously, and another endpoint for the client to poll for completion.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update your Spring Boot at least to version 2.4.3 and higher